# Referencing Powershell array in move-item command

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell, directory

I'm having some trouble with a script. I'm attempting to move all the files sitting in one directory to a different directory, referencing arrays for the file paths (see below). For some reason it is not working - when I run the command it silently does nothing.

Here are the contents of the source directory:

- folderA
- folderB

  - subFileA.txt
- fileA.txt
- fileB.txt
- etc

Here is my command:

```
mv .\$PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0]\*  .\$PRODUCTS_NEW_NAMES[0]\newfolder
```

When I run it nothing happens, and no error is thrown. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**: [CB's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520612/cb) answer worked perfectly and is the solution.

Comment: we need to know where $PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES and $PRODUCTS_NEW_NAMES come from. Could you post more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (assuming  `$PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES` and `$PRODUCTS_NEW_NAMES` are valid path!) using `$()` -> variable expansion syntax

```
mv .\$($PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0])\*  .\$($PRODUCTS_NEW_NAMES[0])\newfolder
```

Comment: When I modify the copy line as you suggested and run it, this is the result:

`PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0] : The term 'PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...` <etc>

However when I run `echo $PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0]` I get the expected output.

Comment: **UPDATE** I missed the double use of `$` in your expression. When I copied your line exactly as you posted it worked perfectly. THANK-YOU!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by CB, this is the solution:

`mv .\$($PRODUCTS_OLD_NAMES[0])\*  .\$($PRODUCTS_NEW_NAMES[0])\newfolder`

Note the parentheses wrapping the array reference with the outside `$` sign.